I'm trying to retrieve properties from viewer forge autodesk but it doesn't work
I'm trying to retrieve properties from my viewer via the model derivate api but I always get a 400 error. Here's my request:
const response = await axios.get(
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/${encodedUrn}/metadata/febf6635-9f7e-5505-8c33-175d630fbea4/properties,
{
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token2}`
    }
  }
);

I've tried with several tokens, several urns (encoded in base 64 and without), putting a dbID, GUID, I must be forgetting some but I think I've tried everything and it still doesn't work, I can't get any property from my viewer.

I made a successful postman request and got the Node.Js-Axios request, Please check if it helps.
const axios = require('axios');

let config = {
  method: 'get',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <Token>'
  }
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});




hello varunpatil , even with your request it doesn't work, are you using modelguid in your request? it's written that you have to use it in the api doc.

yes, i'm using guid as well, removed it by accident while deleting my guid. Please test now.
